# Connect to my server via SSH from external network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have just installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am planning to use it as my server. This server is mainly collecting the data so I have applied a static public IP address from my department.

Currently the data can be send to a UDP port of this IP address from external network, so I think this address is definitely a public IP address. (Please let me know if any better way to make sure of this, the address starts from 147.#.#.#).

Now the problem is **how can I connect to this server via SSH from external network?**

I have already installed ssh on both my server and my computer, and I can connect my server **in the same network** by:

```
    ssh user@ip.address
```

However, when I back to home, this doesn't work. It shows "Operation timed out".

I have also allow the access of the port 22 from anywhere in my Ubuntu server, and the port is listening when I using

```
    netstat -tuplen
```

The server is working for 24 hours, because the data was saving automatically.

Please let me know if I there are any possible solution or anything configuration need to be modified.

Comment: On which interface was assigned public ip address?

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy Not sure what interface you indicated, but I think my department has allocate me a individual ip address but they can control this. I have already sent data package from external network to a UDP port and it received, so I think it is not like a "router" control.

Comment: I think it's a router problem. Your department create port forwarding from public nets to local network only for udp port, not for ssh tcp 22 port.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy thanks for your advice, I will check with them next business day.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy I have checked with department and it seems they close port 22 to external network, so I have use another port and the problem solved! Thanks for your idea!

Answer (score 0):

First go to that server where you have connect using ssh and check, in which port ssh service is being running using

```
sudo netstat -nltp
```

command. And check this port is open publicly or not. Also check your firewall configuration that this port is publicly allowed or not.

Then try connecting to that server using command mentioned below.

```
ssh -i <pem-file> user@ip-address -p <port-no>
```